# how to hide these password and email from URL in express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, mobile-website

`http://localhost:3000/user?email=abc@gmail.com&pass=abc123`
how to hide these password and email from URL.

actually, I'm making a login page where the user will input email and password. but after typing credentials, the URL is changing to
`http://localhost:3000/user?email=abc@gmail.com&pass=abc123`

code for login page is attached below.

```html
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <form action="/user" method="GET">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name='email'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name='pass'>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-success">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe if you change the method of the form to POST instead of get

Comment: https://medium.com/@brockmrohloff_12324/auth-why-http-post-7c4da662cfa2

Answer (score 1):

You should use POST method.

```
  <form action="/user" method="POST">
```